# FFMpeg - adding a video codec

Tags: ffmpeg

I've read the tutorials found on this site
[Adding new CODEC to ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636226/adding-new-codec-to-ffmpeg)

but I can't seem to apply them to my situation. I have a Mpeg-4 based proprietary codec used in a CCTV system. I'd like to decode it back into the base Mpeg-4 or other format. The codec is dll based - where the dll is found in my c:/Windows folder. I followed the steps in the Cook tutorial (http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=FFmpeg_codec_howto)- but am lost on developing my own .c file similar to the libavcodec/cook.c - can I not point to the dll file for this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'point the dll file for this'? Point it to whom (or what)? The only way you can make ffmpeg use this DLL is by writing C code.

Comment: Have you ever found out how? I'm having the exact same situation where I need to encode a video into an AVI with a custom proprietary codec that I installed in Windows. Adobe media encoder is the only program that "sees" the codec and can encode to it. But I would like ffmpeg to be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I spent the last couple of days toying around with several ideas. I found that it's easier to extract the video using a frame server like AVISynth and serving the frames to FFMPEG as images to re-encode into whatever desired format is needed. This worked nicely but it's not a very fast/scale-able solution as the frames are literally extracted as the video plays.

Any other solutions out there. How does one embed the codec directly into FFMPEG, especially since it's a VfW codec leveraging FFDSHOW.

Thanks